# Creating big MUXes and shift registers on FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog

I'm working on a guitar tuner project on FPGA. For this I have to pass the sound signal (16bit/1024Hz sampling) from the ADC to a FFT block but I want the FFT block to be clocked with much higher frequency than the sampling of the sound, and also I want to so some FFT overlapping. The FFT block performs the transform on 1024 samples, 16 bits for each sample.

So I want to store the sound samples in a big SIPO shift register (1024 samples, 16 bits each, which corresponds to 1 second of sound) and I want to pass it to FFT block every 1/8 of a second (every 128 samples) using a big MUX (1024 of 16bit-width buses, so over 16k connections between SIPO and MUX). Every 1/8 of a second the ADDR bus would scan through a MUX (and pass the whole shift register data to FFT block) with a frequency much higher than the clock of the SIPO block.
See the picture.

[image: block scheme]

- Is this way of making it viable?
- Is there any example of implementation of such blocks (preferably in Verilog)?
- Would it fit in my already heavily utilized Cyclone II EP2C35F672C6N? I've already implemented most of the project (including FFT block), see the compilation report below.
- Is there any better way of doing it?

[image: compilation report]

Comment: Use dual-clock RAM.

Comment: A dual port RAM (@user110971 dual clock is not required here.) will offer you high memory amounts (you need 16 kb = e.g. halve Xilinx BlockRAM). The read address works as a big multiplexer.

Comment: @Paebbels OP wants to read at a different clock rate. That’s why I suggested it.

Comment: @user110971 Oh, sorry my mistake. I focused to much on the block diagram.

Comment: Thank you guys, that was exactly what I was looking for. Simple, elegant, efficient.Thanks!